# Eigenvaules of a symbolic matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues

If I try to find the eigenvalues in following way, mathematica gives something else other than algebraic expression, how to obtain algebraic expression ??? 
Please suggest something .

```
 m = {{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}, {g, h, i}};
 Eigenvalues[m]
```

Comment: The `Root` is telling you it doesn't know how to compute that root for arbitrary symbolic entries. Is it a real-valued matrix? What else can you assume about it?

Comment: I don't think there is anything wrong with having `Root` objects, but if you are a masochist, you could use `ToRadicals @ Eigenvalues[m]`.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't want the `CharacteristicPolynomial` instead? The `Root` expressions and it are basically equivalent. Give `CharacteristicPolynomial[m, \[Lambda]]` a look and see if that doesn't make you happier.

Comment: @b3m2a1 Thanks for writing!, Yes entries are real!

Comment: @CarlWoll Thanks for suggestion :)